# MatTableDataSource making alphabetical order mistakes

Tags: angular, sorting

I have the MatTableDataSource and MatSort directives set up on a table on my page, and they work great for the most part. However, I've noticed that it's making one curious mistake when alphabetizing the following fields in one of the columns:

`↑
Company - David Moore
Company - David Moore
Company - Contractor
Company - Contractor
Company Inc. - Beta Testing
Company Inc. - Beta Testing`

Why is it sorting D before C? Both alphabetical and numerical order are working fine everywhere else but in this case. Could it be something with the hyphen in between confusing it?

Answer (score 0):

So it's been a while since I've used the `MatSort` directive, but I don't *think* the [`MatSort` directive](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview) actually sorts anything for you. I *think* it just provides you with the UI for a sortable table, and you need to handle the sorting yourself. If this is the case, my guess is your other data just happens to be properly sorted (for the most part).

You can check out the [example code for `MatSort` from material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples). The directive doesn't handle the sorting (they provide a `sortData()` function).

Comment: That's not how mine is working... I followed the instructions [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview/#sorting) to set it up, and it doesn't say anything about a `sortData()` function. That would be useful if I had a bit more control over it.